# r - Create linestring from two points in same row in dataframe

Tags: r, geometry, line, r-sf

I was wondering if there is a way to create `linestring` from two points given in the same row in a dataframe in a new geometry column. In other words longitudes and latitudes of the two points are given in a dataframe like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), lon1 = c(1,2), lat1 = c(3,4), lon2 = c(5,6), lat2 = c(7,8))
```

where `lon1` and `lat1` represent the coordinates of the first point and `lon2` and `lat2` are the coordinates of the second point. The desired dataframe would have two rows and two columns - the `id` column and a `geometry` column.

I tried with `sf::st_linestring` but seems this function only works with matrices.

Desired dataframe:

```
desired_df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), lon = c(1,2,5,6), lat = c(3,4,7,8)) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4236) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = FALSE) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Update - 30th Jan 2021

The issue with my original answer is it doesn't correctly set the bounding box.

Today I would use this approach using `sfheaders` and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(sfheaders)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

## To use `sfheaders` the data needs to be in long form

dt1 <- dt[, .(id, lon = lon1, lat = lat1)]
dt2 <- dt[, .(id, lon = lon2, lat = lat2)]

## Add on a 'sequence' variable so we know which one comes first
dt1[, seq := 1L ]
dt2[, seq := 2L ]

## put back together
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2), use.names = TRUE)
setorder(dt, id, seq)

sf <- sfheaders::sf_linestring(
  obj = dt
  , x = "lon"
  , y = "lat"
  , linestring_id = "id"
)

sf

# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 6 ymax: 8
# CRS:            NA
#   id              geometry
# 1  a LINESTRING (1 3, 5 7)
# 2  b LINESTRING (2 4, 6 8)
```

---

### Original Answer

An alternative approach using `data.table`

require(data.table)

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)

sf <- dt[
    , {
        geometry <- sf::st_linestring(x = matrix(c(lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2), nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
        geometry <- sf::st_sfc(geometry)
        geometry <- sf::st_sf(geometry = geometry)
    }
    , by = id
]

sf::st_as_sf(sf)
# Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 5 ymax: 7
# epsg (SRID):    NA
# proj4string:    NA
# id              geometry
# 1  a LINESTRING (1 3, 5 7)
# 2  b LINESTRING (2 4, 6 8)
```

Answer (score 12):

```r
df = data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), lon1 = c(1,2), lat1 = c(3,4), lon2 = c(5,6), lat2 = c(7,8))  
df
```

```
##   id lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2
## 1  a    1    3    5    7
## 2  b    2    4    6    8
```

Here is another way, going through WKT:

```r
library(sf)
df$geom = sprintf("LINESTRING(%s %s, %s %s)", df$lon1, df$lat1, df$lon2, df$lat2)
df = st_as_sf(df, wkt = "geom")
df
```

```
## Simple feature collection with 2 features and 5 fields
## geometry type:  LINESTRING
## dimension:      XY
## bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 6 ymax: 8
## CRS:            NA
##   id lon1 lat1 lon2 lat2                  geom
## 1  a    1    3    5    7 LINESTRING (1 3, 5 7)
## 2  b    2    4    6    8 LINESTRING (2 4, 6 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for the WKT implementation.  It is a bit less intuitive, but is very easy to read and takes FAR FAR FAR less code if you're starting with a df with start/end columns.

Comment: In all my sf spatial temporal travels, I somehow often encounter this problem, and this solution is the most elegant in my opinion, far less cumbersome than nesting, mapping, etc...

Answer (score 7):

We can loop through the rows, with `pmap` and apply the `st_linestring` on a `matrix` created

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
out <- pmap(df[-1], ~
               c(...) %>%
                matrix(., , ncol=2, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
                st_linestring) %>%
          reduce(st_sfc) %>%
          mutate(df, geometry = .)

out$geometry
#Geometry set for 2 features 
#geometry type:  LINESTRING
#dimension:      XY
#bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 6 ymax: 8
#epsg (SRID):    NA
#proj4string:    NA
#LINESTRING (1 3, 5 7)
#LINESTRING (2 4, 6 8)
```

Comment: is there a possibility the linestring column to be a geometry column instead of a list ?

Comment: @adl  Can you check if the change is okay

Comment: the result is still a list. Each row has a list in the lstring column instead of just the linestring

Comment: @adl What about now

Comment: the format is ok, but the content inside the linestring is not correct. The desired dataframe should be like the following: df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), lon = c(1,2,5,6), lat = c(3,4,7,8)) %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4236) %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = FALSE) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

Comment: @adl  I think I missed the `st_sfc` earlier.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the purrr-magic that has happend here. What does `c(...)`in `pmap(df[-1], ~c(...))` do exactly? Would you mind replacing the formula `~` notation with an anonymous function?

Comment: In addition, `reduce(st_sfc)` ony works with two rows.. if the dataframe is longer than that, an error is returned  (`Error in vapply(lst, class, rep(NA_character_, 3)) : 
  values must be length 3,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 2`)

Comment: @Ratnanil  It is just to concatenate `c`.  You could use anonymous function call, but part of the reason people use these functions are to make it clean, compact etc (that is also subjective).  Regarding the error, you may have to check the behavior of `st_sfc`

Answer (score 3):

This solution also uses `purrr`'s `pmap`, obtaining the result in the desired format

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf) 

df <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"), lon1 = c(1,2), lat1 = c(3,4), lon2 = c(5,6), lat2 = c(7,8))  

make_line <- function(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
    st_linestring(matrix(c(lon1, lon2, lat1, lat2), 2, 2))
}

df %>%
    select(-id) %>% 
    pmap(make_line) %>% 
    st_as_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
    {tibble(id = df$id, geometry = .)} %>% 
    st_sf()
```

Result:

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  LINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 3 xmax: 6 ymax: 8
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  id            geometry
  <fct> <LINESTRING [°]>
1 a           (1 3, 5 7)
2 b           (2 4, 6 8)
```