# How to efficiently create Linestrings from points?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

I have geom POINTs in two separate data frames. What I want to do is to connect points with a line (later on a map) so that's why I want to create Linestring for each pair of points from those data frames. I made it like this:

```
coordsCust <- table %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lonCust","latCust"), crs = 4326)

coordsApp <- table %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lonApp","latApp"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_geometry()
```

and Linestring:

```
lines <- st_sfc(mapply(function(a,b){
  st_cast(st_union(a,b),"LINESTRING")}, 
  coordsCust$geometry, coordsApp$geometry, SIMPLIFY=FALSE))
```

This code works, I can create Linestrings for each pair of points, row by row:

```
LINESTRING (14.035 51.65182, 14.33418 53.53346)
LINESTRING (20.42767 49.98073, 16.62978 52.31037)
LINESTRING (20.18762 50.03337, 16.62978 52.31037)
LINESTRING (19.04625 49.79234, 16.62978 52.31037)
LINESTRING (21.35808 50.92382, 16.62978 52.31037)
```

The issue is that for 30 000 rows this solution works really slow - about 21 seconds. Is there any other way to create linestrings from points? Something that works much faster? I searched for some solutions on the web but in vain. I've read something about converting sf to matrix and using `pmap` but have no idea how to implement it here.

**UPDATE:** if I want to use sfheaders::sf_linestring function I need to join geometries from both datasets. I do it like this:

```
df <- cbind(coordsCust,coordsApp)
```

and the final data frame (I showed most important part of it) is shown below:

[image]

Unfortunately sf_linestring doesn't work properly on this dataframe. I need to create linestring between POINTs for each row separately as shown on the screen.

Comment: Take a look at this other answer by @SymbolixAU : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922422/7547327.  It looks similar to your problem & you might be able to use it with `sfheaders` for its speed.

Comment: Yes, I saw it either. The issue is that all those functions accept only numeric values, not geometry features. So I can't pass geom points to `st_linestring` or  `sf_linestring`, only numeric values (e.g. coordinates of float type). Or maybe I'm wrong, I just noticed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an exmaple data set it's hard to completly answer your question. But if you can get your data.frame into 'long' form, then `sfheaders` can do this in an instant

```r
n <- 30000
df <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n)
  , y = rnorm(n)
)

df$id <- rep(1:(n/2), each = 2)

sfheaders::sf_linestring(
  obj = df
  , x = "x"
  , y = "y"
  , linestring_id = "id"
)

# Simple feature collection with 15000 features and 1 field
# geometry type:  LINESTRING
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: -4.297631 ymin: -4.118291 xmax: 3.782847 ymax: 4.053399
# CRS:            NA
# First 10 features:
#   id                       geometry
# 1   1 LINESTRING (0.2780517 0.243...
# 2   2 LINESTRING (0.4261505 2.503...
# 3   3 LINESTRING (0.8662821 -0.11...
# 4   4 LINESTRING (-0.5335952 -0.1...
# 5   5 LINESTRING (1.154309 -1.352...
# 6   6 LINESTRING (0.05512324 -0.4...
# 7   7 LINESTRING (1.945868 -0.744...
# 8   8 LINESTRING (0.0427066 -0.08...
# 9   9 LINESTRING (0.06738045 0.41...
# 10 10 LINESTRING (0.4128964 -0.04...
```

Comment: I have two seperate datasets with geom columns (POINTs) and in sfheaders case I see that I need to join them. I did it like this: `df <- cbind(coordsCust,coordsApp )`, then added id: `df$id <- seq(1:nrow(df))` and finally: `sfheaders::sf_linestring(obj = df, x = "geometry", y = "geometry.1", linestring_id = "id")`. Unfortunately I got error: `Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].` I also added some details to my main post above.

Comment: seems I can't make it between geometry points, only between coordinates being floats/numeric